# Two arrays with keys to json

Tags: php, json, xml

I need to know how to store this data into one or two arrays with keys and export them into json format.

Here is the XML input, that I'm parsing:

```
<a id="12">
    <n>Usa</n>
<a id="28">
    <n>Maroko</n>
</a>
<a id="33">
    <n>Finland</n>
</a>
<a id="41">
    <n>Russia</n>
</a>
```

I haven't problem to parse this data, but how should I store this data into array with keys ("id", "country") and export into json with json_encode. I would like to get this output:

```
[
   {
      "id":"12",
      "country":"Usa"
   },
   {
      "id":"28",
      "country":"Maroko"
   },
   {
      "id":"33",
      "country":"Finland"
   },
   {
      "id":"41",
      "country":"Russia"
   }
]
```

I know, very simple, but I can't find the answer. Many thanks

Comment: Show how you parse the data.

Comment: Where's the code that you get that json format?

Comment: @aldrin27 the OP is asking for it ;)

Comment: @RobbieAverill I see. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy with parsing the data from XML then to put data into an array in PHP just do it like this:

```
$data = []; // empty array
$data[] = array("id" => "12", "country" => "Usa"); // push new data array into array
$data[] = array("id" => "28", "country" => "Maroko");
$data[] = array("id" => "33", "country" => "Finland");
$data[] = array("id" => "41", "country" => "Russia");
```

Then to encode it into JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($data);

print $json;
```